# Sql server xpath conditionnal query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath

I have a table where one field called 'configuration' is type of XML:

```
<configuration>
  <element value="john" />
  <element value="kevin" />
  <element value="lisa" />
  <element value="david" />
  <element value="mike" />  
</configuration>
```

What I would like to do, is to retrieve all the table records or at least count the table records that have a field 'configuration' containing at least one 'element' attribute containing a 'value' attribute equals to 'lisa'.

What I have for the moment, is a query that can retrieve the 'value' attribute of the specified 'element' position, for example:

```
select Configuration.value('(/configuration/element/@value)[0]', 'nvarchar(max)') // returns me 'john'
select Configuration.value('(/configuration/element/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') // returns me 'kevin'
```

Comment: Any reason, why you don't simply use a `LIKE...` expresiion? Such as `SELECT *
  FROM @t
  WHERE CAST(config AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%element value="lisa"%'`?

Comment: Because they would be awful for performance @Tyron78.

Comment: Yes I can. But I saw this as an occasion to discover xpath essentialy. Also, would not the request be more slow with the cast and the like?

Comment: @Larnu I think this depends on NUmber of nodes, length of the string and number of records, or am I mistaken? As long as the XML isn't that big, the cast should work pretty fine.

Comment: If you have few (100?) rows, maybe @Tyron78, but why code a solution that is going to steadily suffer more and more performances issues as the data gets larger?

Comment: You are absolutely right @Larnu. Thought ab it too "short termed" there... however, I already managed to bring the XPATH etc. to its limits, trying to search a Table with loads of records and each containing three huge XML columns... was pretty tricky - and I guess it's still quite slow... but you are correct: the XML functionalities are better than the LIKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of pseudo-SQL in the absence of a dataset, and a bit of guesswork; in that I (think) you simply want to return the rows(?) where there is a the node `configuration/element` has the `value` property `'lisa'`. **IF** my guess is right, then something like this will work (you'll ened to replace object names in Braces(`{}`):

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM [{Your Table}] YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [{Your Table}] E
                   CROSS APPLY E.[{Your XML Column}].nodes('configuration/element') C(E)
              WHERE E.[{Your ID Column}] = YT.[{Your ID Column}]
                AND C.E.value('./@value','varchar(50)') = 'lisa');
```

*Example:*

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT 1 AS ID,
           CONVERT(xml,'<configuration>
  <element value="john" />
  <element value="kevin" />
  <element value="lisa" />
  <element value="david" />
  <element value="mike" />  
</configuration>') AS XMlCol
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID,
           CONVERT(xml,'<configuration>
  <element value="craig" />
  <element value="donald" />
  <element value="jenny" />
  <element value="jayne" />  
</configuration>') AS XMlCol)

SELECT *
FROM VTE YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM VTE E
                   CROSS APPLY E.XMlCol.nodes('configuration/element') C(E)
              WHERE E.ID = YT.ID
                AND C.E.value('./@value','varchar(50)') = 'lisa');
```

*This only returns the row with an ID of `1`.*

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below,

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml='<configuration>
  <element value="john" />
  <element value="kevin" />
  <element value="lisa" />
  <element value="david" />
  <element value="mike" />  
</configuration>'
    SELECT   T.c.value('./@value','nvarchar(250)'  )    As element         

    FROM @xml.nodes('//element') AS T(c)
```

[image: and the result is]